# Kazoo "Connection dropped" error when connecting to local zookeeper server

Tags: kazoo

I started a local zookeeper service and tried connecting to it with python kazoo client.

However i keep getting,

> Connection dropped: socket connection erorr: The handle is invalid

On the server side, i see,

> Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed socket.

Can someone enlighten me no how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: I also got the same errors. I'm connecting to Zookeeper on Linux server. It has something to do with Windows + Kazoo (zk client), since it works out ok for my macintosh machine. Already turned off firewall but still no avails :/

Comment: Ok i know the answer. kazoo==2.9.0 does not works well with Windows. I have tried to remove it and install kazoo=2.8.0 and now it's all works again. Am using zookeeper 3.6 btw.